# Search Imap folders for unread emails with Mailkit and Powershell

Tags: powershell, imap, mailkit

I want to search all my Imap folders for unread emails with Mailkit and Powershell. But I cant even list all the folders. Here is the code:

```
$cl = New-Object MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient([mailkit.protocollogger]::new([console]::OpenStandardOutput()))

#connect
$cl.Connect($mailserver, $port)
$cl.Authenticate($username,$password)   
$cl.GetFolders($Cl.PersonalNamespaces[0])
```

The result is always: "**Folder is not currently open**." But I think I would need to read the folder objects first to open them?
Interestingly, the protocollogger lists all my folders fine:

```
Connected to imaps://.................
S: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN ENABLE ID IDLE LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- MOVE NAMESPACE QUOTA SASL-IR SORT SPECIAL-USE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT UIDPLUS UNSELECT WITHIN AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN] IMAP server ready H mieue103 15.4 IMAP-1MRDBi-1ixnXt3r6a-00NV8i
C: A00000000 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN AGQucmfhgffhtFjZSghgQAjrhgrTc1OTg4NjUweHttztYj
S: A00000000 OK AUTHENTICATE completed
C: A00000001 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN ENABLE ID IDLE LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- MOVE NAMESPACE QUOTA SASL-IR SORT SPECIAL-USE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT UIDPLUS UNSELECT WITHIN APPENDLIMIT=140000000
S: A00000001 OK CAPABILITY completed
C: A00000002 NAMESPACE
S: * NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
S: A00000002 OK NAMESPACE completed
C: A00000003 LIST "" "INBOX" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN)
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Subscribed) "/" INBOX
S: A00000003 OK LIST completed
C: A00000004 LIST (SPECIAL-USE) "" "*" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN)
S: * LIST (\Archive \HasChildren \Subscribed) "/" Archiv
S: * LIST (\Drafts \HasNoChildren \Subscribed) "/" Entw&APw-rfe
S: * LIST (\Sent \HasNoChildren \Subscribed) "/" "Gesendete Objekte"
S: * LIST (\Trash \HasNoChildren \Subscribed) "/" Papierkorb
S: * LIST (\Junk \HasNoChildren \Subscribed) "/" Spam
S: A00000004 OK LIST completed
C: A00000005 LIST (SUBSCRIBED) "" "*" RETURN (CHILDREN)
S: * LIST (\HasChildren \Subscribed) "/" Work1
S: * LIST (\HasChildren \Subscribed) "/" Work2

... long list of all my folders ...

S: A00000005 OK LIST completed
```

But I just get the error message back:

```
format-default : The folder is not currently open.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], FolderNotOpenException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MailKit.FolderNotOpenException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log shows that the code snippet you pasted is working fine.

You are not getting the exception from any of the code that you pasted.

You are getting the exception from code after the code that you pasted.

To fix the exception you mentioned, you need to call the `Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite)` method on the folder you are trying to search before you can call `Search()`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209125/discussion-on-answer-by-jstedfast-search-imap-folders-for-unread-emails-with-mai).

Comment: To summarize the discussion for others: the error does indead come the last line "$cl.GetFolders($Cl.PersonalNamespaces[0])".
I have still no clue why.